# Would it be possible to work for a client?

Tags: job-change, job-offer

My client has asked me to work for them. I see there's a clause in my contract like this: The Employee agrees that during the term of the agreement and for a period of three months following the expiry or termination of this agreement for any reason, the employee will not, directly or in directly: (1) solicit or attempt to solicit business from the company's clients (2) induce the company's client to withdraw, cancel or decrease the amount of business such client does with the company

Would I be safe moving on to work for the client?

Comment: Sounds like something to take to a contract lawyer.

Comment: Definitely a legal question, which we don't answer here.

Comment: There is no circumstance where I would risk this. You havea solid chance of losing your main income over this and losing your professional reputation.

Comment: What does the contract that they signed with your current employer state?  Normally those things would prevent them from even attempting to hire you.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of no way where you would qualify as "safe" if you were to do this.

For starters, your employer can sue you.  I'm not going to address the legal question as to whether they would win or lose, but don't minimize that win or lose, they can indeed sue you. That will cost you money one way or another, again whether you win or lose.

But to me, this isn't a legal question so much as it's an ethical question. Clearly your employer doesn't want you to be poached or they wouldn't have put that clause in your employment contract. You agreed to that contract and now you're considering leaving because of what I see as a potential technicality. But is it ethical?

There are also 2 practical matters that you need to consider.  If you go to this client, you go there giving them absolute proof that you're not loyal. In my opinion, this increases your expendability. It's like marrying someone who cheated on their husband to be with you.  You already know they'll be unfaithful if the opportunity is right. :)

Lastly, you're destroying any reputation you may have. No future employer will see you going to your client as anything but disloyal and indefensible. I personally don't think it's worth it.

EDIT: I just reread it and would like to add that under part 2, your going to work for them could absolutely be seen as inducing them to leave or terminate their relationship with your employer. You're essentially removing a huge reason to use your employer so they can pay you directly.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you're soliciting if they ask you first. There are situations where the company wants to expand the amount of work needed that you provide, so they hire you as an employee and continue to maintain the billable hours with another contract worker through your former employer. This way they have you to provide continuity on the project and hopefully stay on longer since you're full time.

Usually contractors have ways to get bought out of the contract. Other then getting lawyers involved, you could just be upfront with your current employer and let them know you want to pursue the unsolicited offer.

My guess is, the company who wants to hire you, isn't aware of your agreement. You'll need to disclose this to them. They may be under the impression they can hire you for less than the contract.

Answer (score 0):

> "The Employee agrees that during the term of the agreement and for a period of three months following the expiry or termination of this agreement for any reason, the employee will not, directly or in directly: (1) *solicit* or *attempt to solicit* business from the company's clients (2) *induce* the company's client to withdraw, cancel or decrease the amount of business such client does with the company"

You are NOT soliciting, attempting to solicit and you haven't done anything to induce - at least, that's what I am gathering from your narrative. You look good so far as the sentence you quoted is concerned because it is the client who is taking the initiative and the client is practically putting their offer in your hand. However, I have no idea what the rest of your employment contract looks like. And I wouldn't make any determination that's final unless I went through your contract as a whole. Best to have a lawyer or paralegal spend one hour over the full contract, and that they give you their expert opinion upon reading the contract as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

If you have watched Demolition Man, you know the most important question is:

> .. or else?

What is the cost of breaking this agreement and is your client ready to pay that if it becomes known? Or are you ready to pay it?

Also, how illegal is it to break this agreement? Can you go to jail for it?

That's all legal questions, so best ask a lawyer. He can also tell you if you are breaking the agreement at all.